# What is the best tool to rip laminate flooring planks to width?

Tags: flooring, laminate

Can you please tell me what tools work best to cut a laminate flooring plank to a narrower size and so that the cut is perfectly straight?

Kind regards.

Comment: Do you mean thinner (less raised off the floor) or narrower (not as wide when looking down at it)?

Comment: I meant not as wide when looking down at it.

Comment: Table Saw.  It's really the only tool you should use for this type of cut.

Comment: I tried to cut the laminate flooring plank with a jigsaw and it did NOT want to cut even close to a straight line. I used another laminate flooring plank clamped to the laminate flooring plank i want to cut and my measurements were all very accurate and i used a special laminate blade in my jigsaw BUT still it did not want to cut a straight line.

Comment: Chris, this could be a answer expand on how to set the rip fence and a safety push block to keep hands away from the blade+.

Comment: Generally speaking, you only cut laminate lengthwise to fit the 'last row' against the wall, and in these cases, you can hide the edge with baseboard and/or corner-round. If you have to do a cut that will be visible (and there are many ways to avoid this, depending on room layout) then you might consider putting a raised threshold transition piece on top which can also hide the edge, though it adds a small lip to the floor.

Comment: A table saw is expensive and requires experience to use safely.There are small and low 'table' saws available at Home Depot (maybe for rent) which are designed specifically for the cuts needed in installing flooring, both cross and lengthwise. The type I have seen has a circular blade of maybe 5 inches diameter and one uses it on the floor so that it is easy for one person to keep the piece flat on the saw without roller supports.

Answer (score 2):

Use a flooring saw like this type Skill Flooring Saw. Much much safer and easier to use than a table saw. Look at the video in the link.

[Here](http://www.homedepot.com/p/Skil-7-0-Amp-4-3-8-in-Corded-Flooring-Saw-3601-02/205329478?cm_mmc=Shopping%7CTHD%7CG%7C0%7CG-BASE-PLA-D25T-PowerTools%7C&gclid=CjwKEAiAgavBBRCA7ZbggrLSkUcSJACWDexAKYohP8XZiP3ahVNAczNpJRmSFLS7mcvKncbO-ITQahoCqt_w_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds)